Is assigning simpler hypotheses higher probabilites the only way to define a reasonable prior probability distribution?
One can think of an infinite number of hypotheses that explain the same data. In Bayesianism, hypotheses have certain prior probabilities of being true (i.e. their probability of being true prior to coming across any evidence for or against them).
Now, if one assigns prior probabilities in such a way where they continue to get smaller and smaller the more complex or "longer" the hypothesis is, it is possible for the addition of all of those probabilities to still sum up to 1 (which is a requirement in probability theory).
One of the more formal ways this is done is through Solomonoff's theory of inductive inference through the use of what is called a "universal prior".
Is this the only way to define a valid prior probability distribution over hypotheses? I suppose one can simply assign 0 to a few hypotheses to get out of this, but in Bayesianism, this is not considered reasonable, because you can epistemically never rule out any hypotheses unless they are contradictory. This is important because the probability of a hypothesis often correlates to the degree of belief you should have in a particular hypothesis in Bayesian thinking.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"Improper" priors
There are many valid assignments of non-negative values as priors. They need not even sum to 1. Such a scenario is referred to as "improper priors" because they are not probability distributions. However, they can still be used as the starting point of Bayesian inference.
A commonly used "improper prior" is the non-informative uniform distribution, even over an infinite interval. After application of Bayes' rule, the posterior probabilities will still sum or integrate to 1.
Piecewise priors built around the Solomonoff prior
Consider a piecewise prior based on the Solomonoff prior, but with a few scattered "high complexity" hypotheses specifically assigned to have a high probability, with the probability of the others all accordingly decreased to maintain the integration to 1. That would be a counter example to the Solomonoff prior being the only possible prior.
Any form that can arise in a posterior can also be a prior
As well, any posterior is by construction also a potential prior. So just take any posterior distribution that resulted in a somewhat complex hypothesis as the most likely, and use that as a prior. Such prior need not arise after actual Bayesian inference. One can adopt any form that could arise in a posterior as a prior. That would be a counter example to the Solomonoff prior being the only possible prior.

If they do not sum up to 1, how is it a valid prior probability distribution?

@syed: It recognizes that the answer may be "none of the above."

The way I would assign probabilities in the absence of data would be to take an initial best guess and refine as data came in. But I'm an engineer, possibly a scientist; I have no problem with admitting it's always best current theory and subject to revision or replacement if something better turns up.

I’m not sure about the legitimacy of the piecewise prior but would appreciate a mathematical proof although that may be out of scope for this site. As for the posterior probability comment, that would be a different exercise altogether, since of course, one may now weigh specific hypotheses higher based on evidence that would seem less arbitrary than doing it with prior probabilities. I suppose one could also rule out certain hypotheses after evidence is gathered and more reasonably assign a posterior of 0 (even if the ad hoc modification of the hypothesis remains non zero)

Yes and no.  For a proper prior, it is true that, for any epsilon there must exist an N so that P(n>N) < epsilon.  However, there are no real restrictions on where that N might be.  e.g. the Poisson distribution.
Let's suppose that the world even can be perfectly described with finite language.  Now, let's consider the distribution of hypotheses based on the length n of their English language description.
You seem to want your prior on hypotheses to follow an Exponential distribution, which is decreasing in probability from 0 all the way out to infinity.  This seems unlikely, because hypotheses of 1 character would be the most favorable.
However, this is far from the only choice of valid distributions.  Consider Poisson(lambda=100,000,000,000).  This would correspond to a case where most of the world needs about 100 billion characters to describe correctly.  In this scenario "simpler hypotheses are more likely" is still true in some sense, where by "simple" we mean "less than a trillion characters".  OTOH, it would put most knowledge that isn't a mere approximation out of human hands forever.

@Syed "the poisson distribution does not have a non zero probability for every possible positive integer"  --  it does.

Interesting answer. I suppose that this touches on what it means to be simple then. However, for every Poisson distribution, correct me if I’m wrong (since I’m not a mathematician), the probability of a very small number will still be in general higher than a very high number. If so, it seems the general trend of very simple hypotheses being more likely than very complex hypotheses would still be true. Or to put it another way, there seems to be no way to define a distribution where the most complex hypotheses get the highest probabilistic weight.

"the probability of a very small number will still be in general higher than a very high number" This hinges crucially on what you mean by "very small" and "very high".  For a given N, it is possible to construct a Poisson distribution so that N is the most likely value.  While I think that your argument is valid, I do not believe that the conclusion is nearly as strong as you would like - all you get is an existence result, i.e  there exists a level of complication so that hypotheses more complicated that that are guaranteed to be unlikely, but you don't know what that level is.

@Syed basically, you get a nice result when considering an infinite set of hypotheses, but since we mere mortals are limited to a finite set of them, we get no results over the part of the distribution that we actually have access to: it could be literally any valid distribution.  All you get is that "the tail" - which can be arbitrarily far away - is small.

are we really limited though? We might be limited in considering them in practice, but given that we cannot rule out an infinite number of them, it seems that it may make no sense to assign zero credence to any of them either, thus implying that we should give an infinite number of hypotheses some nonzero probability, even if we can't think about them all for practical reasons.

Since computable theory length is bounded below by 0 and form a denumerable set where each theory is an atom with (prior) probability > 0, we are forced to conclude that the "tail behavior" of any such prior that sums to 1 (i.e., proper) must be "eventually" decreasing, in the following sense:

limk → ∞ maxh:L(h)=k P(h) = 0

This is just an instance of a necessary condition for an infinite series to converge:

If ∑ ai converges then limi → ∞ ai = 0

Now, for this to actually work, we cannot simply say the probabilities decrease in the limit, we need the total probability of all hypotheses for each length L to be eventually bounded by 1/(Lp), p>1 for this to actually converge (the p-series test). I assume Solomonoff defined the probability of a particular hypothesis of length L in such a way that this happens as you encounter the combinatorial explosion of hypotheses as lenght increases.
However, this is a very broad statement -- there are an infinite number of ways to assign probabilities in a convergent way. Solomonoff picked one that has intuitive appeal if you are trying to give a probabilistic justification for Occam's razor.

I think the first formula doesn't make sense. argmax() returns a hypothesis, which is not a number. So it doesn't make sense to talk about a limit approaching 0 of hypotheses that are not numbers.

@user80226 correct — my error :-) corrected

No, length and complexity of theories are not objectively defined, and given definition or given infinite sets of theories may not grant this. Though this is a reasonable expectation for arbitrary phenomena.
As counterexamples: we can consider infinite sets of theories that have the same length or complexity, or simply define length or complexity as same for all theories (semantics). Or we can define length or complexity as the inverse of their typical definition, just to mess with the maths.
Only with additional restrictions auch as when considering algorithms representing theories and specific definitions of length and complexity there is a little less leeway.
But even then for a problem we might consider the same algorithm but with different constant parameter values as different theories, granting infinite variants as theories with same length and complexity (depending on the definitions still), meaning any distribution that assigns gradually lower values to higher indices in some enumeration of those variants does not assign lower values to greater lengths and complexity, since all lengths and complexity are equal in such a domain.
